# Should I store a very long array in back-end or front-end?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript

In my angular application, I have a very long array and would like to put it some where I could access very easily from my front-end don't slow down my application, there are multiple options and I don't which one is the best. Should I store it in:

my API

```
app.get('models', (req, res) =>{var models = ['m1', 'm2', 'm3', ..., 'mn'];
res.send(models);
});
```

In API DB:

```
app.get('models', (req, res) =>{
      Models.find({}, (dara, err){
      res.send(models);
    })
});
```

in my front-end:

```
// models.ts
```

in a variable in my component

any comment will be appreciate.

Comment: local storage did u give it a try, you can retrieve throughout your app'n hassle free.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you mean by "store" and probably avoid using terms like "best practice". Just try and show us what you actually need to do instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Since it is very big array, I think it could have a bad influence on performance

Comment: You're being very abstract, which is not good for a question here. I'm prompting you to add detail to your question and explain what you think you need to do in a way that people can clearly see it and give you a clear answer. So [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53441040/edit) with more descriptive detail is advisable.

Comment: This really depends on how it is used. Try several ways and see what works best for you. Consider initial load time of the client, caching on the client, ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you want to do, so:

**In the Frontend**
Is never a good idea try to have data on your frontend, this implicates that the user will request for a full list of data that will only use or read a few.
If you still consider that you wanna do it there: You can have always in a constant, then you can consume that using local storage(be careful with the space limitation 10MB), global variables or just a file to import
Note: Using suspense or any lazy loading you will be able to avoid sending this data at the same time that everything else.

**In the Backend**
Yes, is the best place to have information that you need to request, there you can use a DB to store and a GET to request it is the common and best approach.
Note: Avoid send all the list in one request in you can, try indexing or use pagination, for most of the cases you don't need have such big arrays on FE.

But at the end, is more a decision based on what you want to build that only one good answer.

Hope this helps you!